# How can I list ALL grants a user received?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-grant

I need to see all grants on an Oracle DB.

I used the TOAD feature to compare schemas but it does not shows temptable grants etc. so there's my question:

How can I list all grants on a Oracle DB?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

If you want more than just direct table grants (e.g., grants via roles, system privileges such as select any table, etc.), here are some additional queries:

System privileges for a user:

```
SELECT PRIVILEGE
  FROM sys.dba_sys_privs
 WHERE grantee = <theUser>
UNION
SELECT PRIVILEGE 
  FROM dba_role_privs rp JOIN role_sys_privs rsp ON (rp.granted_role = rsp.role)
 WHERE rp.grantee = <theUser>
 ORDER BY 1;
```

Direct grants to tables/views:

```
SELECT owner, table_name, select_priv, insert_priv, delete_priv, update_priv, references_priv, alter_priv, index_priv 
  FROM table_privileges
 WHERE grantee = <theUser>
 ORDER BY owner, table_name;
```

Indirect grants to tables/views:

```
SELECT DISTINCT owner, table_name, PRIVILEGE 
  FROM dba_role_privs rp JOIN role_tab_privs rtp ON (rp.granted_role = rtp.role)
 WHERE rp.grantee = <theUser>
 ORDER BY owner, table_name;
```

Comment: You may not have the right to see the sys.dba_sys_privs table.

Comment: Absolutely correct. See your DBA.  If they refuse, they may have legitmate security concerns. Seeing the contents of these views gives a user information they would not be able to have otherwise.

Comment: It would be interesting to left join the `role_role_privs` table and then `CONNECT BY PRIOR granted_role = role` to recurse into transitive role privileges...

Answer (score 39):

Assuming you want to list grants on all *objects* a particular user has *received*:

```
select * from all_tab_privs_recd where grantee = 'your user'
```

This will not return objects owned by the user. If you need those, use `all_tab_privs` view instead.

Answer (score 25):

Sorry guys, but selecting from all_tab_privs_recd where grantee = 'your user' will not give any output except public grants and current user grants if you run the select from a different (let us say, SYS) user. As documentation says,

> ALL_TAB_PRIVS_RECD describes the following types of grants:
>
> ```
> Object grants for which the current user is the grantee
> Object grants for which an enabled role or PUBLIC is the grantee
> ```

So, if you're a DBA and want to list all **object** grants for a particular (not SYS itself) user, you can't use that system view.

In this case, you must perform a more complex query. Here is one taken (traced) from TOAD to select all object grants for a particular user:

```
select tpm.name privilege,
       decode(mod(oa.option$,2), 1, 'YES', 'NO') grantable,
       ue.name grantee,
       ur.name grantor,
       u.name owner,
       decode(o.TYPE#, 0, 'NEXT OBJECT', 1, 'INDEX', 2, 'TABLE', 3, 'CLUSTER',
                       4, 'VIEW', 5, 'SYNONYM', 6, 'SEQUENCE',
                       7, 'PROCEDURE', 8, 'FUNCTION', 9, 'PACKAGE',
                       11, 'PACKAGE BODY', 12, 'TRIGGER',
                       13, 'TYPE', 14, 'TYPE BODY',
                       19, 'TABLE PARTITION', 20, 'INDEX PARTITION', 21, 'LOB',
                       22, 'LIBRARY', 23, 'DIRECTORY', 24, 'QUEUE',
                       28, 'JAVA SOURCE', 29, 'JAVA CLASS', 30, 'JAVA RESOURCE',
                       32, 'INDEXTYPE', 33, 'OPERATOR',
                       34, 'TABLE SUBPARTITION', 35, 'INDEX SUBPARTITION',
                       40, 'LOB PARTITION', 41, 'LOB SUBPARTITION',
                       42, 'MATERIALIZED VIEW',
                       43, 'DIMENSION',
                       44, 'CONTEXT', 46, 'RULE SET', 47, 'RESOURCE PLAN',
                       66, 'JOB', 67, 'PROGRAM', 74, 'SCHEDULE',
                       48, 'CONSUMER GROUP',
                       51, 'SUBSCRIPTION', 52, 'LOCATION',
                       55, 'XML SCHEMA', 56, 'JAVA DATA',
                       57, 'EDITION', 59, 'RULE',
                       62, 'EVALUATION CONTEXT',
                       'UNDEFINED') object_type,
       o.name object_name,
       '' column_name
        from sys.objauth$ oa, sys.obj$ o, sys.user$ u, sys.user$ ur, sys.user$ ue,
             table_privilege_map tpm
        where oa.obj# = o.obj#
          and oa.grantor# = ur.user#
          and oa.grantee# = ue.user#
          and oa.col# is null
          and oa.privilege# = tpm.privilege
          and u.user# = o.owner#
          and o.TYPE# in (2, 4, 6, 9, 7, 8, 42, 23, 22, 13, 33, 32, 66, 67, 74, 57)
  and ue.name = 'your user'
  and bitand (o.flags, 128) = 0
union all -- column level grants
select tpm.name privilege,
       decode(mod(oa.option$,2), 1, 'YES', 'NO') grantable,
       ue.name grantee,
       ur.name grantor,
       u.name owner,
       decode(o.TYPE#, 2, 'TABLE', 4, 'VIEW', 42, 'MATERIALIZED VIEW') object_type,
       o.name object_name,
       c.name column_name
from sys.objauth$ oa, sys.obj$ o, sys.user$ u, sys.user$ ur, sys.user$ ue,
     sys.col$ c, table_privilege_map tpm
where oa.obj# = o.obj#
  and oa.grantor# = ur.user#
  and oa.grantee# = ue.user#
  and oa.obj# = c.obj#
  and oa.col# = c.col#
  and bitand(c.property, 32) = 0 /* not hidden column */
  and oa.col# is not null
  and oa.privilege# = tpm.privilege
  and u.user# = o.owner#
  and o.TYPE# in (2, 4, 42)
  and ue.name = 'your user'
  and bitand (o.flags, 128) = 0;
```

This will list all object grants (including column grants) for your (specified) user. If you don't want column level grants then delete all part of the select beginning with 'union' clause.

UPD: Studying the documentation I found another view that lists all grants in much simpler way:

```
select * from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where grantee = 'your user';
```

Bear in mind that there's **no** DBA_TAB_PRIVS_RECD view in Oracle.

Answer (score 24):

The most comprehensive and reliable method I know is still by using [DBMS_METADATA](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_1_dbms_metadata.htm):

```
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl( 'SYSTEM_GRANT', :username ) from dual;
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl( 'OBJECT_GRANT', :username ) from dual;
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl( 'ROLE_GRANT', :username ) from dual;
```

(username must match case, so usually should be uppercase)

Interesting answers though.

Comment: The username must match the case in which it is stored in the database. For unquoted identifiers, Oracle will implicitly convert the identifier to upper-case so, typically, the username should be upper-case; however, if a quoted identifier is used for the username (which is considered bad practice but is possible) then you would have to match the exact case used in the quoted identifier (which could be upper-, lower- or mixed-case).

Comment: i'm gettings ORA-31608 on OBJECT_GRANT ((

Comment: @SimonLogic that should mean there are no such grants for the user (or the user doesn't exist, or - probably - you can't view existing grants with the privileges you currently have)

Comment: @MatteoSteccolini yep, you're right. there were no object grants per user. by the way your method requires database to be opened in read-write mode (we're using pluggable db).

Answer (score 5):

```
select distinct 'GRANT '||privilege||' ON '||OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME||' TO '||RP.GRANTEE
from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS RP join ROLE_TAB_PRIVS RTP 
on (RP.GRANTED_ROLE = RTP.role)  
where (OWNER in ('YOUR USER') --Change User Name
   OR RP.GRANTEE in ('YOUR USER')) --Change User Name
and RP.GRANTEE not in ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
;
```

Comment: Some explanation would help this answer, for when other people come and find it.

Answer (score 0):

Following query can be used to get all privileges of one user... Just provide user name in first query and you will get all privileges to that

```
WITH users AS
 (SELECT 'SCHEMA_USER' usr FROM dual),
Roles AS
 (SELECT granted_role
    FROM dba_role_privs rp
    JOIN users
      ON rp.GRANTEE = users.usr
  UNION
  SELECT granted_role
    FROM role_role_privs
   WHERE role IN (SELECT granted_role
                    FROM dba_role_privs rp
                    JOIN users
                      ON rp.GRANTEE = users.usr)),
tab_privilage AS
 (SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE
    FROM role_tab_privs rtp
    JOIN roles r
      ON rtp.role = r.granted_role
  UNION
  SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE
    FROM Dba_Tab_Privs dtp
    JOIN Users
      ON dtp.grantee = users.usr),
sys_privileges AS
 (SELECT privilege
    FROM dba_sys_privs dsp
    JOIN users
      ON dsp.grantee = users.usr)
SELECT * FROM tab_privilage ORDER BY owner, table_name
--SELECT * FROM sys_privileges
```

Answer (score 0):

To list all system privileges granted to current user(the user which is connected and owned the session), the following query would work:

`select * from USER_SYS_PRIVS where USERNAME = <CURRENT_USER>;`

The query should execute in current user session and username **MUST** include quotations. For example:

`select * from USER_SYS_PRIVS where USERNAME = 'arash';`