# Toad -- Table Script Generation by Toad Gives Invalid SQL Error (ORA-00900)

Tags: oracle, toad

I am using Toad for Oracle Professional version 10.6.1.3. My goal is to view the script generated by Toad for a selected table. Here are my steps:

1. Log in to my database.
2. Open the Schema Browser.
3. Select the proper schema. The tables are listed.
4. Select the table. The column list is displayed on the right.
5. Click the "Script" tab. An error is returned: "TOAD Error:: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement."

There is no other information given. Some tables give this error; some tables don't. Apparently this does not happen for other members of my team with the same login to the same database, so I am guessing there is some sort of setting or option that I have turned on/off that is causing this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Due to the hint given to me by a commenter about the "Spool SQL" feature, I was able to determine that all of the tables that give me this error contain one or more fields with the CLOB data type. When this happens, a series of SQL statements are ran to get various information about the CLOB. One of these isn't displayed by the "Spool SQL" window, and this is where the invalid SQL error is generated.

Comment: Just seem to remember having a similar issue before, it was solved by granting me some type of access by DBAs. But honestly I don't remember exactly what was it. I suggest checking your grants against one of your teammates. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1301327/821786)

Comment: Also you can spool SQL (Database menu, Spool SQL, Spool SQL to Screen) and find the offending query and report it to the Toad team here... http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/f/10. You can also go through the official Dell support channels if you are current on maintenance.

Comment: Both excellent clues, but no answer yet. Hopefully I can get a DBA to help me investigate grants.